# Display Progress Bar - Programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I was just trying to display a progress bar. I found some reference code to display it. Its rather simple but doesn't appear to be working. This is in C# - Winforms.

Is there something I forgot ?

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
progressBar.Show();
progressBar.Visible = true;
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, if possible, to place it on your form in the Windows Forms designer and set Visible = false. That way, it is not visible from the start and if you need it, you just need to set Visible = true again.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add it to your form as well.

```
this.Controls.Add(progressBar);
```